# How to make credit card payment using logpacker package paypal?

Tags: go, paypal

I am using logpacker package  in golang app to make credit card transaction using paypal, but it returns me `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment: 500` error
My main.go file having this code::

```
package main 

import (
    paypalsdk "github.com/logpacker/PayPal-Go-SDK"
    "fmt"
)

var ClientID = "my-client-id"
var SecretID = "my-secret-key"

func main() {
    // Initialize client
    c, err := paypalsdk.NewClient(ClientID, SecretID, paypalsdk.APIBaseSandBox)
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }

    // Retrieve access token
    _, err = c.GetAccessToken()
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }

    // Create credit card payment
    p := paypalsdk.Payment{
       Intent: "sale",
       Payer: &paypalsdk.Payer{
          PaymentMethod: "credit_card",
          FundingInstruments: []paypalsdk.FundingInstrument{{
            CreditCard: &paypalsdk.CreditCard{
                Number:      "43118885805455",
                Type:        "visa",
                ExpireMonth: "11",
                ExpireYear:  "2023",
                CVV2:        "123",
                FirstName:   "abc",
                LastName:    "abc",
            },
          }},
       },
       Transactions: []paypalsdk.Transaction{{
            Amount: &paypalsdk.Amount{
                Currency: "USD",
                Total:    "7.00",
            },
            Description: "My Payment",
        }},
        RedirectURLs: &paypalsdk.RedirectURLs{
            ReturnURL: "http://...",
            CancelURL: "http://...",
        },
    }
    _, err = c.CreatePayment(p)
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
    }
    //fmt.Println(data)
}
```

After this I am running main.go file and it generates following error
error: `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment: 500`

This is a logpacker package github link: https://github.com/logpacker/PayPal-Go-SDK

Comment: Note that [500 means "Internal Server Error"](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1), that is, the remote web server had some error (not your client), and it likely won't tell you what happened (perhaps for security reasons) but mostly because it wasn't your fault and there's likely nothing you can do about it.

Comment: If I am doing this without golang app, using postman I created payment successfully, Can you suggest me how to get payment approval after creating a payment

Comment: I would contact the package developer and ask them to add more detailed error information. It appears to be available to them, in the response body, but they appear to be throwing it away.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's a best practice to not provide any debugging information in a 500 ISE response since it's a _server_ error (i.e. it would be bad to report things like database connection failures, programming errors, etc to your clients). PayPal needs to get their house in order.

Comment: @maerics You're assuming (1) it actually is an internal server error and (2) it has no further information. I suspect neither is true. But without actually looking at the complete response, it's not possible to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP response code [500 means "Internal Server Error"](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1):

> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

That means your client successfully sent the HTTP request but the server failed to generate an expected response because some problem happened on the server itself and it is the responsibility of the owner of that system to fix it. The root cause could be any number of things (programming error, database problem, networking issue, can of soda spilled on server motherboard, etc.); however, the debugging information exists on the server infrastructure and is generally not (*should not!*) be available to clients since it may contain sensitive information.

It is *possible* that there was some problem in the request that your client issued and, in that case, the server should respond with some sort of [4xx "Client Error"](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4) response. However, we cannot know if that was the case because the server failed to generate a meaningful response.

Your only recourse is to contact the owner of that system, notify them of the error on their server, and hope that they resolve it so you can continue your work.